# How double %% Python Placeholder works

Tags: python-2.7

I don't understand why the output of the following code is `1%3`. Can anyone explain this?

```
print '%d%%%d' %(1%2, 3%4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol `%` when used between integer, give the modulo:

```
1%2 = 1
2%2 = 0
2%3 = 1
```

This is the rest that remains when you divide the two numbers.

When used inside a string, the `%` has a particular meaning: in your case `%d` is an integer number (can be any number of digits). `%%` will be printed as `%`: the first `%` works as an escape sequence. Then you have another `%d`. The two `%d` are replaced by the number resulting from the operations `1%2`, `3%4` which are, respectively, `1` and `3` because `4/3 = 0 with a rest of 3`. Analougus for the `1%2`: `2/1 = 0 with a resto of 1`.

Comment: What about putting '%%' between '%d' how '%%' works with formating?

Comment: I wrote it: `%%` is an escape sequence when formatting: it prints `%`. What do you mean putting `%%` between `%d`??